# Interpreting the R Polynomial Regression output

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I have the following linear regression output with two quadratic terms and I am unsure how you make the general equation from this for predicting values for Y outside of R software. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

e.g. y=-12.02-(0.4117*a)+(0.02673*b)+(0.05613*c)+(0.09945*d)+?????

Thanks

```
lm(formula = y ~ a + b + 
c + d + poly(e, 
2, raw = TRUE) + poly(f, 2, raw = TRUE))

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-24.225  -2.566  -0.284   2.125  29.228 

Coefficients:
                           Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)               -1.202e+01  9.951e-01 -12.079  < 2e-16 ***
a                         -4.117e-01  1.637e-02 -25.143  < 2e-16 ***
b                          2.673e-02  1.066e-03  25.087  < 2e-16 ***
c                          5.613e-02  7.055e-03   7.956 2.15e-15 ***
d                          9.945e-02  3.004e-02   3.311 0.000936 ***
poly(e, 2, raw = TRUE)1    7.549e-01  4.331e-02  17.427  < 2e-16 ***
poly(e, 2, raw = TRUE)2    4.279e-03  5.112e-04   8.370  < 2e-16 ***
poly(f, 2, raw = TRUE)1    1.003e-01  3.862e-02   2.596 0.009457 ** 
poly(f, 2, raw = TRUE)2    9.824e-03  4.004e-04  24.532  < 2e-16 ***
```

Comment: You are probably looking for predict().

Comment: ... + 0.75 e^1 + 4.2e-3 e^2 + ...